# Add terminal session with network to login in screen

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, login-screen, session, gnome-session

I want to add a terminal Xsession to the log in drop down screen. Can anyone let me know how to do this? No desktop, load only terminal with network support.

Booting in recovering from grub lets me do this but I would rather do it from the login screen.

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 with standard install

Please note I have and am in the process of searching for the answer with little luck.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but you could try to copy one of the existing session files in /usr/share/xsessions and alter it to launch xterm, gnome-terminal etc

Comment: Egil, please rewrite your comment as an anwser because it did the trick as follows: New file named terminal.desktop with the following code:[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=This session logs you into Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal 
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Icon=
Type=Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file called terminal in /usr/share/xsessions with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=This session logs you into Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Icon=
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean launching only terminal with no desktop, I don't know how to add this to login screen, but you just could switch to the terminal by Ctrl-Alt-F1 to Ctrl-Alt-F6

Comment: Thank you LiquidPL. That is what I want to do. Launch a terminal with no desktop (with network). I would prefer to choose the option at boot login though instead of booting into the desktop then shutting it down to terminal only.

Comment: It does not shut down, it just switches to another terminal. Press Ctrl-Alt-F7 to return to the graphical one.

Comment: Thanks Egil. The recent issues with NVIDIA and other issues makes it necessary for me to want to have an option to log directly into a terminal session instead of loading the desktop as a backup. This feature is available through the recovery bootup but still would like to have it in the login session options.

Comment: Yup - I don't remember how to shutdown the graphical session in Ubuntu. In others `init 3` should do the work, but Ubuntu uses Upstart and I don't know how to do it here.

Comment: About shutting down the graphical session - check if `sudo stop lightdm` would do it.