# Lightdm: Select Window Manager (disappeared?)

Tags: unity, lightdm, unity-2d

Cant select with what window manager want to start X.

I think its for unity-greeter.

The icon that appears next to your username and let you start X with unity-2d, gnome, unity, kde, etc have gone and I cant switch.

I DONT want to change my default window manager, only switch it on the lightdm screen.
It has disappeared in Ubuntu 12.10 I think.

Anyone?

Comment: use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` command to switch window manager

Comment: It changes default window manager. I want to select it in lightdm as before.

Comment: Yes. Choose lightdm and save it. Reboot the machine. You will be able to see the unity-greeter, where you can select a session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon does not appear if you don't have any other session type available. This is what happens after a clean install.

You need to install some other packages providing entries in `/usr/share/xsessions`, you find which packages with `apt-file search /usr/share/xsessions`.

Comment: True! Last install I have unity-2d and some but I have just done a clean install (sorry for not saying).

Comment: But I have added a file to `/usr/share/xsessions` to have a "terminal session" but it didnt show up. Clues?

Comment: I don't think you can add files to that directory and expect them to show in the login manager. You have to install a package providing such items.

Comment: Read that here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132285/add-terminal-session-with-network-to-login-in-screen